# How to reduce buffering on chromecast for live stream

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Hello I am producing a hls live stream from my phone and sending it over to chromecast over local wifi. I see huge buffering before chromeast could start playing frames.

1. how do i force chromecast to start livestream right away (after recieving first chunk of ts file)
2. how do i control buffering size on chromecast. i can clone sample chromecast reciever app and hack into it if need be.